# WhyJava Bean Pattern is not threadsafe

Tags: java, constructor, javabeans, builder

Joshua Bloch states in Effective Java, 2nd Edition:

One alternative you have to the Telescoping Constructor Pattern is the JavaBean Pattern where you call a constructor with the mandatory parameters and then call any optional setters after:

```
Pizza pizza = new Pizza(12);
pizza.setCheese(true);
pizza.setPepperoni(true);
pizza.setBacon(true);
```

The problem here is that because the object is created over several calls it may be in an inconsistent state partway through its construction. This also requires a lot of extra effort to ensure thread safety.

My Question:-
Is above code not thread safe? Am I missing any basic thing?

Thanks in Advance,

Surya

Comment: Yes, your missing the basic of Java!!! Every new instance of Pizza is called will create a new instance. So NO sharing through multiple threads. Why do you think the above code is not thread-safe?

Comment: my understanding is, we will be creating new instance inside a method(say method createPizza()). When multiple threads calls createPizza() method, they have their own Pizza instance and it is threadsafe. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct!!

Comment: then, my statement is contradicting from what is there in book, right?

Comment: What does it say? Maybe you mis-interpreted?

Comment: Since you are reading Effective Java, you will find that the answer to your question is nicely presented in the chapter "Concurrency."

Comment: Sure, I will go through it. Thanks everyone who helped me to understand this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code that you have shown us involves only one thread, so thread-safety *of this code* is moot.

If multiple threads *could* see the `Pizza` instance, then there are a couple of things to worry about:

1. Can another thread see the `Pizza` instance before you have finished initializing it?
2. When the other thread sees the instance, will it observe the correct values for the attributes?

The first concern is addressed by not "publishing" the references to another thread until you have finished initializing it.

The second one can be addressed by using an appropriate synchronization mechanism to ensure that the changes are visible.  This could be done in a number of ways.  For example:

- You could declare the getters and setters as `synchronized` methods.
- You could declare the (private) variables that hold the attribute values as `volatile`.

Note that the JavaBean pattern doesn't prescribe how beans are constructed.  In your example, you use a no-args constructor and then set fields using setters.  You could also implement a constructor which allows you to pass arguments giving (non-default) initial values for properties.

> This also requires a lot of extra effort to ensure thread safety

Not really.  In this context, it is a small change to make the getters and setters thread-safe.  For example:

```
public class Pizza {
     private boolean cheese;

     public synchronized /* added */ void setCheese(boolean cheese) {
         this.cheese = cheese;
     }

     public synchronized /* added */ boolean isCheese() {
         return cheese;
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you add an example for making the setters / getters threadsafe? It's simple to add the `synchronized` keyword to them, but if you consider all setters part of initialization, you'd need to make sure none of the setters is called while any other Setter is called.

Comment: I don't understand your point.  Adding `synchronized` will do that.

Answer (score 1):

The author says textually :

> **JavaBeans pattern precludes the possibility of making a class immutable and  requires a added effort on the part of the programmer
>   to ensure thread safety.**

I think that the author stresses on the fact that it makes no sense to provide methods that prevent the object immutability and **may** create consistency issues between threads if you object is designed to be immutable : that is it never needs to change once created.

Your question :

> Why Java Bean Pattern is not threadsafe ?

Any class that provides a way to mutate a field is not thread safe.
It is true for JavaBeans methods (that generally don't use defensive copy) but it is also true for any mutable class.

Manipulating a no thread safe class is not necessary a problem if you use it in a context where you have no race conditions between threads.
For example this code is thread safe :

```
Pizza pizza = new Pizza(12);
pizza.setCheese(true);
pizza.setPepperoni(true);
pizza.setBacon(true);
```

because the `Pizza` instance is not declared as a variable that is shared (instance or static field) but it is declared and used in a more restricted scope (probably a method but it could be also a initializer block).

The builder pattern provides a way to build an immutable and so by definition a thread safe object.

For example by using a builder to create a `Pizza` :

```
Pizza pizza = new Pizza.Builder().cheese(true).pepperoni(true).bacon(true).build();
```

Only the call to `build()` creates and returns the `Pizza` object. 
Previous calls manipulate a `Builder` object and return a `Builder`.
So, if the object is immutable, you don't need to worry about synchronizing these calls :

```
pizza.setCheese(true);
pizza.setPepperoni(true);
pizza.setBacon(true);
```

as these method don't need to be provided. So they cannot be called.

---

**About how to have thread safe JavaBeans**

If you are in a context where the `Pizza` instance could be shared among multiple threads, these calls should be done in a synchronized way  :

```
pizza.setCheese(true);
pizza.setPepperoni(true);
pizza.setBacon(true);
```

These could be declared as `synchronized` method and or `Pizza` fields could be volatile but these could not be enough.

Indeed, if a Pizza should change its state according to its own state or even according to another object, we should also synchronize the whole logic : do the checks until the state modification of the `Pizza`.

For example suppose the `Pizza` has to add some units of Pepperoni only one time :

The code could be :

```
  if (pizza.isWaitForPepperoni()){
      pizza.addPepperoni(5);
  }
```

These statements are not atomic and so no thread safe.

`pizza.addPepperoni(5);` could be called by two concurrent threads even if the one of the threads already invoked `pizza.addPepperoni(5);`.

So we should ensure that no other thread calls `pizza.addPepperoni(5)` while it should not (The pizza will have too much Pepperoni) .
 
For example by doing a synchronized statement on the `Pizza` instance :

```
   synchronized(pizza){
      if (pizza.isWaitForPepperoni()){
          pizza.addPepperoni(5);
      }
   }
```

Comment: I don't think that is what he is asking. He is not asking how to make the code above thread-safe.

Comment: @Minh Kieu You are right. I edited to set the context.

Comment: "Pizza pizza = new Pizza.Builder().cheese(true).pepperoni(true).bacon(true).build();
" This is not one call. This are 5 calls.

Comment: @Angel O'Sphere only the call to `build()` creates and returns the Pizza object. Previous calls manipulate only a Builder object and return a Builder.